# How to prevent Prometheus from adding port to the specified target?

Tags: prometheus

I have specified Prometheus target as below:

```
- job_name: 'web_api'

  static_configs:
    - targets: ['u-agrawalo-web.api.lb.example.com']
```

But Prometheus is searching for http://u-agrawalo-web.api.lb.example.com:80/metrics

Is there a way to prevent prometheus from adding a port to the url specified? i.e. I want prometheus to just query http://u-agrawalo-web.api.lb.example.com/metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These URLs are equivalent, most likely the software on the other end is incorrectly handling them differently and needs fixing.

Comment: I agree. Actually, the endpoint is https://u-agrawalo-web.api.lb.example.com/metrics and it looks like scheme defaults to http. Also, the endpoint needs Kerberos authentication.

Comment: It says "server returned HTTP status 401 Unauthorized"

Comment: Is there a way to authorize these requests?

Comment: Prometheus doesn't support kerb auth, if you don't have a way to turn if off for that endpoint you'll need to use a HTTP proxy that can handle it for you.